# register is being called a net in my testbench -- won't compile

Tags: verilog, test-bench

My testbench won't compile because it keeps claiming that `clk` is a net. 
 To my understanding, `reg` is not a net and should be allowed in the LHS of an equation.

---

```
module testbench // testbench module has no ports
(
reg clk,    
reg [3:0] d,                    //latch inputs
wire [3:0] q        //latch outputs
);
// instantiate circuit under test


ringcounter UUT1( 
    .q(q),
    .d(d),
    .clk(clk)
);

initial
    begin
        clk = 0;
    end


always 
    begin
        #10 clk = ~clk;     //toggle clock every 10ns
    end

endmodule
```

The error I'm getting is

> (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "clk".

Answer (score 3):

If your comment is correct ("testbench module has no ports"), then don't use parentheses after the module name.  Use a semicolon there, and after each reg/wire declaration:

```
module testbench; // testbench module has no ports
reg clk;   
reg [3:0] d;                    //latch inputs
wire [3:0] q;        //latch outputs
// instantiate circuit under test
```